# How to sort an Excel pivot table across several dimensions?

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table, spreadsheet

Suppose I have the following pivot:

```
Dim 1 | Dim 2 | Count
A     | B     | 1
A     | C     | 3
B     | A     | 2
B     | D     | 4
```

when right-clicking on any number in `Count` column, I've selected *Sort from largest to smallest* and god the following sorting:

```
Dim 1 | Dim 2 | Count
A     | C     | 3
A     | B     | 1
B     | D     | 4
B     | A     | 2
```

What is really required is to sort the pivot table across the dimensions to get the following result:

```
Dim 1 | Dim 2 | Count
B     | D     | 4
A     | C     | 3
B     | A     | 2
A     | B     | 1
```

How can I do that please? Complementary requirements: copying the values is less acceptable as the source data and filters might be updated, so I'd like to keep the sorted pivot in automatic sync, VBA coding is another less feasible option.

Comment: Would it be Ok to add a hidden working field to the source data and the PivotTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to right click on the column you want to sort by and click Sort.

Comment: It's a pivot table, not a regular table, so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: is there a limitation with OLAP by chance?

Comment: Did you try right-clicking on the actual column values?
http://i.imgur.com/dKDOzYc.png

Comment: I've got to the bottom of the problem - the sorting doesn't work with some data sources (i.e. OLAP)